# asp.net core 3.1 Identity - redirecting to login after SignInAsync() when referrer is Stripe

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, stripe-payments

We have an issue with a asp.net core 3.1 MVC application. The application is using the built in asp.net Identity feature. The application is working well for existing users. If you hit any `[Authorized]` route, you are redirected to the login page as expected.

However, rather than have a registration process in our app, for new users, we onboard them via Stripe Checkout. Upon successful payment, stripe redirects to a specific route in our application `/conversion/success/{sessionid}` where sessionid is the Stripe session. This action is marked as `[AllowAnonymous]`.

We then pull the necessary customer details from Stripe, create a user in our repository via `UserManager<T>`. We then call `SignInManager<T>.SignInAsync()` to sign in the new user, before redirecting the new user to the `[Authorized]` home page.

This process works perfectly when running locally on our test machines. Also, when running on our production server (Azure App Service) it also works perfectly when we hit the route manually through the browser.

However, when we actually run the process through Stripe, complete a payment and let Stripe redirect the customer, we get a strange behaviour.

The conversion route is hit, the user record is created, the sign in process completes but upon redirection to home page, the authentication middleware takes over, says it's not authenticated and redirects to the login page.

Just to compound matters further, if you then simply type in the home page route in the browser, the user is in fact logged in exactly as expected and the application works perfectly.

Using Fiddler to intercept the calls and look at headers, etc. we can't see why there would be a different behaviour when coming from Stripe as opposed to typing directly. We've even tried redirecting from a different website to our registration process and that works as expected too.

Any idea why we are seeing this behaviour?

---- Update ---

If, rather than redirect to home page at the end of the onboarding process, we simply show a simple View with an anchor link to home page, the user can then go to home page as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you're rendering the page before authentication has been completed? Since UserManager uses a cookie to establish the user's session, authentication needs to complete **before** any response headers or body is set so that the `Set-Cookie` header can be sent in the response.

Based on what you described it sounds like the user is hitting the homepage after the redirect **without** having the authentication cookie. Where I'd start debugging this is by using your web inspector with "Preserve log" turned on and going through the Stripe Checkout process. Then, inspect the headers sent to the browser when you land on the redirect page & make sure the authentication cookie is set.

Between requests to Stripe and SignInAsync it seems possible that there might be a missing `await`, so the redirect is happening before the authentication context is updated. Hard to say more without seeing your code!

Comment: thanks for your response. The page is definitely rendering last, after the onboarding process and SignInAsync. Your suggestion about a missing await was a great thought - I hadn't considered that at all. However, I do await the call correctly (that would have been it!)

Comment: So are you seeing the Set-Cookie header in the response when Stripe redirects from Checkout to your page then? This might be a good case to reach out to Stripe support, though off the top of my head there's really nothing special about that redirect that could cause the behavior described.

Comment: hpar thanks for your response. I've got a ticket outstanding with Stripe. I agree, nothing special about the redirect as far as we can see. And the authentication cookie/header is set and is present when redirecting to the home page. And yet it still redirects to Login! For the time being, we've created an AllowAnonymous view which contains some JS that then redirects to the home page. This works ok, but it shouldn't have to exist.